# Multiple flask applications served by a single gunicon server

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I have a service, which contains 2 Flask-applications - let's name them **app** and **monitoring_app**  running  on **different** ports. **monitoring_app** is an utility service which provides metrics collected with [prometheus_client](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python). I have faced up with an issue trying run them under the [Gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org) server properly.

I have read through the similar topic:
[Multiple Flask Application in single uwsgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57802947/multiple-flask-application-in-single-uwsgi) 
but it seems my problem can't be solved with [Dispatcher Middleware](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/appdispatch/).

I can start these applications without Gunicorn like this:

```py
from threading import Thread
import os
from my_project import create_app, create_monitoring_app


def start_app(my_app):
    my_app.run(host="localhost",
               debug=True,
               port=int(os.environ.get("API_PORT", "5000")),
               threaded=True,
               use_reloader=False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app()
    app_thread = Thread(target=start_app, daemon=True, args=(app,))
    app_thread.start()

    monitoring_app = create_monitoring_app()
    monitoring_app.run(host="localhost",
                       port=int(os.environ.get("OPS_PORT", "5001")),
                       threaded=True,
                       use_reloader=False,
                       debug=True)
```

It works ok for development, but it runs under Flask development server which is not ok for production environment. With Gunicorn I can start them separately:

```
gunicorn "my_project:create_monitoring_app()" -b "[::]:$OPS_PORT" &
gunicorn "my_project:create_app()" -b "[::]:$API_PORT"
```

but then they will be in different interpreters and I can't use **prometheus_client** of **app** in **monitoring_app** what is critical for me

What can I do to achieve same behavior as if I run these applications from my development environment? Or may be I am doing something wrong and I should do it in another way?